# How to execute android application in command line of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

If for example I have simple android project and I want to run it from command line of Android Studio. How can I do that? I want to enter some commands into command line:

> ant debug adb install bin/MyFirstApp-debug.apk

Where can I find command line in Android Studio? Thanks for any help.

Comment: that command doesn't make any sense, you need to leave out `adb debug`.  Why not just type it into a command prompt?

Comment: @Kristopher Micinski how to open command prompt?

Comment: open the terminal on your system and type

Comment: win-r cmd on windows, atr-alt-t on linux I believe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update: 
New location in Android Studio: `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Terminal`.

Also, the default keyboard shortcut is `alt + F12`.

Old:
Go to `Tools` -> `Open Terminal`. Works great.

Comment: When I run "adb devices" from the command terminal, it doesn't list any devices, instead it says "'adb is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @the_prole, you have at least three options to fix that: 1. Another SO question, 2. Perform that command in your `<android-sdk>/platform-tools/` directory (that's where the command is located), 3. [Add that directory to your "path"](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20how%20to%20add%20to%20path) in your environment variables (so that the terminal will search that directory for the commands).

Answer (score 11):

I've tried to use the Windows terminal to do the cmd like "adb logcat", but it says "adb is not recognized." 
So I just found a solution provided by the following link, which works fine for me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjutSsQn2Ic

**Steps to setup adb on windows :**

1) Open command promt and type adb

you will see this message :'adb' is not recognized

2) Now Download sdk(adt bundle) from
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

the ADT Bundle includes everything you need to begin developing apps: Eclipse + ADT plugin Android SDK Tools Android Platform tools The latest Android platform The latest Android system image for the emulator

3)Extract the zip to c drive with name "AndroidSDK" Open the platform-tools folder, you will find the adb.exe file

4)Now click on my computer and select properties

5) Click on advanced system settings

6) Choose environment variables

7) From system variables, choose path and double click on it

8)At the end of variable values put a semicolon ;
and address of platform tools folder,
for me it is
C:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools

9)Now click OK

10)Open command prompt and type adb

11) You will see it is working

Answer (score 6):

`View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Terminal (Alt + F12)`

appears to be the menu navigation for newer versions of Android Studio (1.2.1.1, at this time)

Answer (score 1):

To open terminal in android studio Android Studio Arctic Fox

**View -> Tool Window -> Terminal** (or) **Alt + F12**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can either run your `apk` on an emulator or directly on a device via the `adb` CLI.

###### Devices

Find your preferred plugged in device ID:

```sh
adb devices
```

Install onto your device (or emulator if no device ID) with the following command:

```sh
adb -s "your-device-ID" install bin/MyFirstApp-debug.apk
```

You can also ***run*** with the following command:

```sh
adb shell am start -n com.app.name/com.app.name.LaunchActivity
```

###### Emulators / AVDs

List your emulators:

```sh
emulator -list-avds
```

Run a specific emulator:

```sh
emulator -avd device_name
```

eg:
`emulator -avd Pixel_5_API_30`